# Getting timestamp() value using C# client

Tags: neo4jclient

Just a quick one, I have a node that gets a value set using the value of timestamp(), when I query for the node using

```
public List<Thing> ListThings()
    {
        return client.Cypher
                     .Match("(thing:Thing)")
                     .Return<Thing>("thing").Results.ToList();
    }
```

I have a class called Thing that looks like this:

```
public class Thing{
    public string name {get; set;}
    public int id {get;set;}
    public DateTimeOffset timestamp{get;set}
}
```

We create the 'thing' ahead of time by using:

```
Create(thing:Thing{id:6,name:'thing1', timestamp:timestamp()}) return thing
```

I get every value back apart from timestamp when calling from my script, which is a little annoying, any ideas? I get all the values back using the query in Neo4j browser, so I was wondering if I was actually doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tatham is right, the `timestamp()` returns a long that's not convertible into `DateTimeOffset` or `DateTime`. One of the problems is that the returned value is Milliseconds since 1/1/1970, so you need to calculate that, unfortunately, JSON.Net can't do that automagically.

If you can change your `Thing` class you could have a property that isn't serialized but is calculated by the `Timestamp` property, something like this:

```
public class Thing
{
    private static DateTime _epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    private long _ts;

    public long timestamp
    {
        get { return _ts; }
        set
        {
            _ts = value;
            TimestampAsDateTime = _epoch.AddMilliseconds(_ts);
        }
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public DateTime TimestampAsDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

The `TimestampAsDateTime` property would only ever be available in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the Neo4j console and just run `RETURN timestamp()`, you'll see the result is a number like 1440468541547. That can't be de-serialized to a `DateTimeOffset`, especially as there's no offset component. You'll need to use a different type in C#: probably `long`, or maybe `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your excellent answers, you solved the problem, but I am using a slightly overlooked (on my part) solution.
As the data type for timestamp() is long I am just going to return that from the service. We have the ability to handle that perfectly using the clients in-built Date object.

It was a mistake on my part, I wrongly assumed that timestamp would have been DateTime, but then I got an error about it and was advised to use DateTimeOffset, which I did, never really considered long as an option.

Please remember I am from a MSSQL background and some things, although easier to do, take a different perspective to grasp.

Thanks to you both though, appreciate the time taken to assist.